# Samsung Galaxy S10 cannot resolve mDNS .local

Tags: android, mdns

Samsung Galaxy S10+, Android 12.

According to Samsung, mDNS is now supposed to work on Android 12 and newer. On my Windows 10 machine I can ping and access the webpage on power.local (an Arduino ESP8266 web server running mDNS). However, my phone cannot resolve the power.local address. I've set the DNS to the main router, same as on Win 10.

Running ***ping power.local*** on Win10:
[image]
Running ***ping power.local*** on Samsung Galaxy:
[image]

Win 10 correctly first ask the regular DNS and then performs a mDNS multicast.
The phone only resorts to regular DNS and never performs a multicast DNS.

mDNS, simple explanation
https://www.androidpolice.com/android-mdns-local-hostname/

mDNS, technical
https://blog.esper.io/android-dessert-bites-26-mdns-local-47912385/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like my phone somehow was not eligible to the mandatory update which included the mDNS package.

To find out if your phone has the package you can run:
*adb shell dumpsys package com.google.android.resolv*

If it does not return the package, it is not installed on that phone.